# Ошибка fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied

Tags: git

Привет всем, при коммите в гите выскакивает ошибка

> fatal: could not open '.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG': Permission denied

Поиск не помог, права доступа к файлу полные, попробовал менять текстовый редактор с вима на блокнот++.

Что еще можно попробовать сделать?

Ось: Вин7.

Comment: А пробовали его удалить? (для параноиков - предварительно куда-либо скопировав)
Также, проверьте права на саму папку .git.

кстати, полные права - это ещё не значит полные. Возможно, у Вас полные права для одного пользователя, а работаете под другим.

Comment: Сейчас вот конкретно решаю только удалением, но, каждый раз, он, понятное дело, пересоздается. Удалять каждый раз, как я делаю коммит - немного муторно. Полные права для всех пользователей, перепроверил, как на сам файл, так и на папку. Владельцев поменял с Администратора на текущего пользователя - 0 эффекта.

Comment: Возможно это конфликт Яндекс.Диск и git.
Яндекс.Диск меняет атрибуты скрытых файлов, что нарушает работу git.

Comment: На основании чего сделан вывод, что там вообще яндекс-диск есть?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Снимите атрибут "Скрытый" с файла COMMIT_EDITMSG.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14067841/how-do-i-get-commit-editmsg-to-open-from-the-correct-location